# Duplicated output from chemical curated data

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

I just discovered something rather odd while using chemical curated data in *Mathematica*. I tried to extract `EdgeRules` for some molecules and some molecules gave me several copies of said `EdgeRules` as a list. Is this a bug? Have any of you found similar things happening with other curated data?

Example:

```
ChemicalData[#, "EdgeRules"] & /@ {"Glutamine", "Alanine", "Serine"}
```

This input gives me 1, 3 and 2 copies of the `EdgeRules` of the given molecules.

Comment: It is good that you have found the answer to your question, but you should remove it from the question and make it an answer. Answering one's own question is not only allowed, it is encouraged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. *Mathematica* interprets the input string as a list of all available molecules that contain the input string as a substring.

```
ChemicalData["Alanine"]
```

> ```
> {"DAlanine", "DLAlanine", "LAlanine"}
> ```